# Countries tags are not used in some specific questions

Tags: discussion

Mostly new users ask their question and they make questions (the quality is irrelevant in this point) hoping an answer that is segregated in one specific country. There are examples of when we talk about the Parliament but not specify the country or they assume we know they're talking about United Kingdom.

Ususally, there are questions referring to the United States political system but in the question there's no evidence they speaking about it. I think a good idea would be to specify in the tag if the question is addressed to a specific country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, including tags for nation-specific questions is the standard here.

New users might not always be aware of this, so if someone asks a question without a nation-specific tag, and you know which nation it applies to, you should edit the question and add the tags.

If you don't know which tag to apply, you can ask the OP for that information, and you can suggest that the add the appropriate tag themselves.

Comment: I do this very often. As non-american, I find so many questions with this problem.